# Through FSO VBA - Files are not moving, please go through my code, I don't understand why files are not moving. I am trying to execute it but msg box

Tags: vba, filesystemobject

Please go through my code, correct me where I am wrong, files are not moving from folder to folder.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MoveFiles()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromDir As String
Dim ToDir As String
Dim FExtension As String
Dim Fnames As String

FromDir = "C:\Users\B\Source Folder"
ToDir = "C:\Users\B\Destination Folder"

FExtension = "*.*"
Fnames = Dir(FromDir & FExtension)

If Len(Fnames) = 0 Then
MsgBox "No files or Files already moved" & FromDir
Exit Sub
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FSO.MoveFile Source:=FromDir & FExtension, Destination:=ToDir

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You are missing a `\` at the end of your `FromDir` which will separate the path from your filenames.

For your info: `&` is not really combining path and filename, but just concatenating two strings, so it never adds the `\` itself.

### Correction possibility 1

You can add it to the definition of FromDir:
`FromDir = "C:\Users\B\Source Folder\"`

### Correction possibility 2

Add it to these lines of code dynamically:

`Fnames = Dir(FromDir & "\" & FExtension)`

`FSO.MoveFile Source:=FromDir & "\" & FExtension, Destination:=ToDir`

### Another remark

You should also separate `FromDir` from the error text, like this:

`MsgBox "No files or Files already moved: " & FromDir`